# Snapping two columns to correct positions

Tags: jquery, html, css

With **Jquery** I am using the `.offset()` method to position two columns that are 100% of the page height and simply act as the drop-shadow for the edges of the actual content.

The CSS I have applied to these columns is:

```
div#lshade,
div#rshade
{
    width: 60px;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
}

div#lshade
{
    background: url(/_private/display/layout/lshade.png) repeat-y;
}

div#rshade
{
    background: url(/_private/display/layout/rshade.png) repeat-y;
}
```

And here is the JQuery I use:

```
function loaded()
{
    setInterval("fixShade()", 33);
}

function fixShade()
{
    var left = $("#lshade");
    var right = $("#rshade");

    var cont = $("#content").offset();

    left.offset({top: 0, left: cont.left});
    right.offset({top: 0, left: cont.left + 900});
}
```

This all worked as expected up until my page content became long enough to need to scroll. Once the page scrolls, the columns move upward with the page, even though their position is set as fixed.

I'm assuming that using offset() changes this property from fixed.

My goal is to have those two columns always snapped to the top of the page and 100% of the page height (as position: fixed; would do).

I'm thinking the solution will be something along the lines of setting the position to be horizontally aligned where they need to be and vertically snapped to the position that you have scrolled to (so the top of the window).

Here is the website I am working on at the moment, if it helps: http://cherishbeauty.businesscatalyst.com/treatments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

offset seem to be only getting your left or right shading element heights. Try

```
left.offset({top: 0, left: cont.left}).css("height",$(window).height());
```

or

```
left.offset({top: 0, left: cont.left}).css("height",$(document).height());
```

or best bet

```
left.offset({top: 0, left: cont.left}).css("height",$("#innerContent").height());
```

or you need to get the height of another element that goes all the way down. Not sure what that one is. maybe innerContent

Comment: It didn't work at first and then I replaced **window** with **document** and now it works perfectly - thanks for the push in the right direction.

Comment: glad you found what you needed with that ;)